# Relay DC voltage rating, absolute or relative?

Tags: voltage, relay

Is the dc voltage rating for a relay taken to be the absolute value on the high voltage terminal or the voltage difference between the input and the connected terminal?

To clarify, if the relay in the picture has a Vdc rating of 30V, is this circuit correct?
[image: example relay circuit]

Answer (score 2):

The voltage rating for a relay contact is the maximum voltage permitted between the contacts when open - the relay contacts don't  know or care where you think "zero volts" is.

A relay will have some maximum insulation rating, but the normal, commonly 'advertised", rating will be for the contacts themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The main rating is for the relative voltage difference between the contact points, because high voltages would causes arcing as the contacts approach or separate.

But there is also an absolute voltage capability to consider because of the insulation.  You won't generally see that specified.  I don't think 76V would give you any issues.